# How to find what index page a post is on?

Tags: posts, wp-query, options

Here is a simple example of what I am wanting to figure out.

Say I have WordPress set to show 5 posts per page. And say I there is a post 17 posts back chronologically.

The formula would be 17 / 5 = 3.4. Round up 3.4 to a whole page of 4 and that post 17 posts back is on the 4th index page.

Now... How to do this programmatically...

The number of posts on each index page is determined by the `get_option( 'posts_per_page' );` option.

If all I have is the post's id, how do I figure out how many posts back it is chronologically?

My head first went to `WP_Query`, but it is not a suitable option. The blog this is for has thousands of posts and it runs out of memory before I can get anywhere to determine where the post is at.

Does anyone have an clever suggestions?

Comment: Can I ask why you need to figure this out?

Comment: I wrote my own Redis caching plugin and this was one of the missing pieces. I needed to clear the post's corresponding index page when a comment was left so the comment count on the index page could be recached to show an accurate comment count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the [suggestion](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/93791/30649) of [Mridul Aggarwal](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/22495/mridul-aggarwal), I came up with the following query, which returns a post's chronological position for a given post id.

The post id, post title, and post date can be removed and are just used for debugging / verifying the results.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM (
        SELECT
            ID as id
        , post_date
        , post_title
        , @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS position
        FROM
            wp_posts
        , (SELECT @rownum := 0) AS rownum
        WHERE
            post_type = 'post'
        AND post_status = 'publish'
        ORDER BY
            post_date DESC
    ) as post_position
WHERE
    id = 12345 /* REPLACE THIS WITH THE POST ID YOU WANT */
```

Make sure you replace the `12345` for the post id with the post id you want to find the position for.

You can run this query using `$wpdb->get_results`. More details on `$wpdb` can be found in the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb).

With the query results, I can then calculate what paginated index page the post is on using the PHP logic below.

```
// Get posts per page option.
$posts_per_page = get_option( 'posts_per_page' );

// Calculate what index page a post is on.
$page_index = ceil( $position / $posts_per_page );
```

And that's it! The `$page_index` variable will hold the magical paginated index page number!

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to do it directly but there's a way to determine the position of a particular row in a mysql query. You can find out how to do it here- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3614666/mysql-get-row-position-in-order-by

Once you have the position you can divide it with the value from `get_option('posts_per_page')` to determine the correct page number.